# Как использовать _id в MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

никак не могу понять, как исопльзовать этот идентификатор? В SQL как-то понятнее было, там просто числа, а тут..

Comment: Это ключ, по которому можно найти данный документ, без использования, каких-либо дополнительных фильтров. Использовать не обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB [не поддерживает транзакционность](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/), поэтому использование числовых ID (а именно, первичных ключей с авто-инкриментом) крайне нежелательно. В теории это можно сделать, например [так](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm), но в этом практичеси нет смысла.

[ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) - это 12-байтовая 16-ричная строка, которая состоит из UNIX Timestamp'a, id машины, процесса, и рандомного счётчика. Это даёт такому идентификатору уникальность и возможность сортировки по нему. Так что, по сути, он может делать всё то же, что и числовой id в MySQL, только вместо integer'a у вас будет hexadecimal.

По опыту работы с проектами, которые попадали мне с числовыми айдишниками в монге, могу с уверенностью заявить, что даже при небольшом росте нагрузки поддержка такой архитектуры превращается в ад. Постоянно появляются дублирущиеся записи, записи в базе перемешиваются друг с другом, авто-инкремент скачет, да и работать с этим практически невозможно.

Если у вас есть конкретные вопросы или проблемы при работе с такими id - спрашивайте конкретнее.

См. так же: [BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)

Answer (score 0):

Я просто добавил еще один идентификатор который использую как в sql, Где то вычитал, что стандартный id можно настроить. Как именно не помню, вроде бы используя mongoose если проект на nodejs